# Turning method with arguments into a validation callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this setup

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_price_relations
  has_many :sales_prices, through: :customer_price_relations (join table)

class SalesPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_sales_prices, dependent: :destroy (join table)
  has_many :products, through: :product_sales_prices
  has_many :customer_price_relations, dependent: :destroy (join table)
  has_many :customers, through: :customer_price_relations  

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :product_sales_prices
  has_many   :sales_prices, through: :product_sales_prices (join table
```

And I use this method to create a new SalesPrice

```
def create_sales_price(company_id: nil, carrier_product_ids: nil, customer_ids: nil, name: nil, margin_percentage: nil)
  sales_price = nil

  transaction do 
    sales_price = self.new({
      company_id:        company_id,
      name:              name,
      margin_percentage: margin_percentage
    })
    sales_price.save!

    customer_ids.each do |customer_id|
      customer_price_relation = CustomerPriceRelation.new({
        customer_id:    customer_id,
        sales_price_id: sales_price.id
      })
      customer_price_relation.save!
    end

    carrier_product_ids.each do |carrier_product_id|
      price_document_relation = CarrierProductSalesPrice.new({
        sales_price_id:     sales_price.id,
        carrier_product_id: carrier_product_id
      })
      price_document_relation.save!
    end
  end
  return sales_price
end
```

In which I give an array of customer and carrier product IDs. I want to perform a validation that makes sure that no customer has been assigned the same carrier product more than once, even across different SalesPrices.

I use this query to find a matching SalesPrice given a customer/carrierproduct id, so in essence, I want to call this method, and only pass the validation if it doesn't find a match

```
def find_sales_price_from_customer_and_carrier_product(customer_id: nil, carrier_product_id: nil)
      self.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN carrier_product_Sales_Prices ps ON sales_prices.id = ps.sales_price_id").
           joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_Price_Relations cr ON ps.sales_price_id = cr.sales_price_id").
           joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers c ON cr.customer_id = c.id").
           where("cr.customer_id = ? and carrier_product_id = ?", customer_id, carrier_product_id).first
    end
```

Problem is, I am unsure on how to turn this into a callback validation, since it takes arguments.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Before saving/creating which record should this validation happen ?

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question

Comment: I suggest using an ActiveRecord Callback such as before_save, in which if you return false, the entire transaction will rollback. Otherwise you can call your `find_sales_price_from_customer_and_carrier_product` method inside your `create_sales_price` and raise `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` to halt the transaction

Comment: Appreciate the reply, but it doesn't really answer my question